# How to make dfsearch on an array of start nodes in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a script which generates n x 1 arrays of start nodes; such arrays can have various numbers of elements (start nodes). For example, it might be
2×1 cell array

```
'B2825'
'B1329'
```

or 5×1 cell array

```
'B1560'
'B1100'
'B1196'
'B1487'
'B1338'
```

etc.

I need to:
a) do dfsearch on a graph for each start node in an array:

```
dfsearch(Ggraph,'B2825');
dfsearch(Ggraph,'B1329');
```

etc.

b) concatenate the results of a number of  dfsearch into a common array of nodes:

```
vertcat(A1..An)
```

I've been trying to write a for loop and a while loop, but am getting all kind of weird messages like:
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions", "Conversion to cell from double is not possible".

For example, this code returns the message below:

```
`n = length(rootnode);`
`i = 1;`
 if n > 1
    while i <  n
        D(:,i) = dfsearch(Bgraph, rootnode(i));


    i = i+1;
    end
 end
```

> Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in fdname3 (line 6)

> Blockquote

in this case 'rootnode' is an 7 x 1 array:
    'B1561'
    'B4272'
    'B2028'
    'B3722'
    'B3629'
    'B2510'
    'B4270'

Comment: We can't really help you unless you show us your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the code which generates arrays of start nodes is not important. It would traverse a graph and return an array of nodes a a time. My task is to write a code which would take a node from an array, run a dfsearch, put results in a new array, take the next node, run a dfsearch, etc.

Comment: n = length(rootnode);

    i = 1;
    if n > 1
        while i <  n
            D(:,i) = dfsearch(Bgraph, rootnode(i,1));
        
      
            i = i+1;
    end
end

Comment: Please add clarifications to the question itself using [edit]. So what error does this code produce? If I had to guess I'd say you needed to use `rootnode{i}`, assuming `rootnode` is your cell array.

Comment: Have you tried my previous suggestion? (Note the curly braces.)

Comment: Yes. When I try D(:,i) = dfsearch(Bgraph, rootnode{i}); the message is: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Comment: Why is that? Have you run it through the debugger?

Comment: I understood why I get  "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." message. I ran dfsearch manually on the nodes. The run on the first node returns 2 x 1 array; the run on the second node returns 18x1 array. Since I'm trying to put both results into the same array, hence the "dimension mismatch". How should I change the code?

Comment: Cell arrays are useful for storing different-sized elements...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in using curly braces on **both** sides: D{i} and rootnode{i}

```
n = length(rootnode);
i = 1;

if n > 1
    while i < (n+1)
        D{i} = dfsearch(Bgraph, rootnode{i});
        i = i+1;
    end
end
```